# vba to transfer code from module vba project to excel sheet vba project

Tags: vba, excel

I've developed an excel addin that imports sheets into the existing one. i would like to be able to double click anywhere and be able to jump back to the first sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, cancel As Boolean)

Sheets(1).Select
cancel = True

End Sub
```

Another program writes a summary excel file. I've developed a add-in macro that when opened and run, Imports the full solution sheets and do some data manipulation. is there a way to transfer this code into the excel sheet vba project? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

use workbook events

so type in ThisWorkbook code pane the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Sheets(1).Select
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. but thats manually doing it. i was hoping vba could automate that step for me. because the excel sheet is generated by another program. i want to be able to load the add in, run the excel add in macro and the code would be inside the worksheets

Comment: You can code this in your addin as an Application level event.  Look it up on CPearson.com

Comment: it's not a _manual_ way at all! f you code that sub in the _existing_ workbook where your add-in is going to add new sheets then all those new sheets will be "affected" as well. Unless the workbook is not _existing_ and it is created by the add-in also along with all its sheets

Comment: @user3598756. Thanks. But i've tried your method and it only works when the code is pasted in my excel file vba project ThisWorkbook code pane and not my add-in vba project ThisWorkbook code pane.
Ill try to explain myself abit more: Another program writes a summary excel file. I've developed a add-in macro that when opened and run, Imports the full solution sheets and do some data manipulation.

Comment: If you cannot write that code once and for all in your "summary excel file" ThisWorkbook code pane than you can have your add-in write it there via VBE object model (see [This site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx))

Answer (score -1):

Press `Alt+F11` to go to VBA development tab and then in the tab on the left there should be displayed your Excel worksheets.

Simply double click on the worksheets you want to apply that feature and paste the code :)

See this image for more details about where to click:
https://www.extendoffice.com/images/stories/doc-excel/doc-drop-down-list-prevent-paste/doc-drop-down-list-prevent-paste-1.png

Comment: thanks for your comment. but thats manually doing it. i was hoping vba could automate that step for me. because the excel sheet is generated by another program. i want to be able to load the add in, run the excel add in macro and the code would be inside the worksheets.

Comment: @MarcusChua: have you tried the solution as per my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that way. If you want to apply that feature automatically on all worksheets use @user3598756 approach :)